# How can I convert a panorama to "Google Sphere" / Panorama for "Google Views"?

Tags: metadata, panorama, google

I have this panorama:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1e0qz92jsb4xibe/test-3000x1500.jpg?dl=0

I edited it in Photoshop and uploaded it to Google, but it isn't recognized as a panorama any more. That's why I added the missing META information using ExifTool:

`-ProjectionType="equirectangular" -UsePanoramaViewer="True" -"PoseHeadingDegrees<$exif:GPSImgDirection" -"CroppedAreaImageWidthPixels<$ImageWidth" -"CroppedAreaImageHeightPixels<$ImageHeight" -"FullPanoWidthPixels<$ImageWidth" -"FullPanoHeightPixels<$ImageHeight" -CroppedAreaLeftPixels="0" -CroppedAreaTopPixels="0"`

But it still isn't recognized. I also used the Google Sphere web app (http://photo-sphere.appspot.com/), but the downloaded version still isn't recognized as a panorama when I upload it to Google...

Thank you for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed that the image already is an panorama, but `photos.google.com` doesn't recognize it. If I upload/open it in `www.google.com/maps/views`, the image shows a little "Google Sphere" icon.

So http://photo-sphere.appspot.com/ works great, only the preview is broken. :)